# Convert list of images to array for import

Tags: php, wordpress, csv

I am trying to import a CSV file into Wordpres but am having trouble with images.  Currently my WordPress site stores images as an array in a custom field called '_images'...

```
a:1:{s:4:"docs";a:4:{i:0;a:1:{s:15:"property_imgurl";s:63:"http://wwww.mydomain.com/image1.jpg";}i:1;a:1:{s:15:"property_imgurl";s:63:"http://wwww.mydomain.com/image2.jpg";}i:2;a:1:{s:15:"property_imgurl";s:63:"http://wwww.mydomain.com/image3.jpg";}i:3;a:1:{s:15:"property_imgurl";s:63:"http://wwww.mydomain.com/image4.jpg";}}}
```

The data I have managed to extract from another site is just a list of images

```
http://wwww.mydomain.com/image1.jpg
http://wwww.mydomain.com/image2.jpg
http://wwww.mydomain.com/image3.jpg
http://wwww.mydomain.com/image4.jpg
```

What is the best way for me to convert these lists of images into an array as above that I can then import as a custom field?  Maybe some sort of PHP parsing script to generate them?

Comment: you  did not mention how you create this list. when ever you are creating this list you can assign each value to an array . http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php

Comment: Please show us your code, and we'll suggest ways to improve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

4th try:

```
$images = serialize( array(
    'docs' => array(
        array( 'property_imgurl' => 'http://wwww.mydomain.com/image1.jpg' ),
        array( 'property_imgurl' => 'http://wwww.mydomain.com/image2.jpg' ),
        array( 'property_imgurl' => 'http://wwww.mydomain.com/image3.jpg' ),
        array( 'property_imgurl' => 'http://wwww.mydomain.com/image4.jpg' )
    ) )
);

print_r( $images );
```

Comment: I'm not trying to update anything with this, I am trying to output the completed array so I can include it in a CSV import

Comment: Thats kind of what I need but the reverse.   Again, I am not trying to update anything so update_post_meta is not useful here

Comment: If you are not trying to update, what do you mean by `import`? Where are you storing the imported data?

Comment: Does it matter?  I just want to echo out the serialized array

Comment: That doesn't work for me, unexpected "property_imgurl"

Comment: Thanks for sticking with it!  Works great now :)